# How to make my website open gracefully on mobile devices?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div {
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#f3c5bd), color-stop(50%,#e86c57), color-stop(51%,#ea2803), color-stop(75%,#ff6600), color-stop(100%,#c72200));
            width: 310px;
            height: 310px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>lol</div>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </body>
</html>
```

But when i open it on my phone instead of showing the red div on the full screen it shows everything small... what am I missing?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add this line into the `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and then you've got to learn some [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), there isn't a short answer for it. You can always post questions while you're reading/learning/writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Make you're div responsive, instead of using 310px use percentages like so:

```
width: 100%
```

And what do you mean by 'shows everything small', please clarify!